# Juego del gato o Tic-Tac-Toe en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles, game

estoy haciendo un juego del gato o Tic-Tac-Toe en Python, pero me encontré con unos problemas que me está costando resolver.

La idea es que sea un juego dinámico de dos jugadores, por lo que el jugador 1 es `X` y el jugador 2 es `O`. Y esto es lo primero que me esta constando hacer, sobre cómo hacer para que cambie de jugador el juego. Ya que siempre empieza el jugador 1 con `X`, y después seguiría el jugador 2 con `O`, pero no se cómo hacer para que cambien. Esta parte iría en la función `def change_player():` que está vacía.

Por otro lado, tengo un problema con la función `def who_wins():`. Esta misma evalúa si gana `X`, `O` o si hay un `empate`. Pero en la anteúltima línea, donde está el `elif " " in lista: continue`, queda trabado en un loop infinito y no se porqué. La idea de esa parte del código es que evalúe si hay espacios vacíos en la tabla, y si los hay, que vuelva a analizar hasta que algún jugador gane la partida o se llene la table y haya empate.

Es case sensitive, por lo que al ingresar `X` u `O`, deben ir en mayúscula. Además,al usar `.split()` es esta parte `n = input("Enter the coordinates: ").split()`, al ingresar las coordenadas de la tabla deben ir separadas con un espacio, ejemplo: `1 1`.

Las coordenadas de las tablas son como las de una matriz:

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)
```

La idea es que empiece con tabla vacía y que el output sea algo así:

```
---------
|       |
|       |
|       |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 2 2
---------
|       |
|   X   |
|       |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 2 2
This cell is occupied! Choose another one!
Enter the coordinates: two two
You should enter numbers!
Enter the coordinates: 1 4
Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!
Enter the coordinates: 1 1
---------
| O     |
|   X   |
|       |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 3 3
---------
| O     |
|   X   |
|     X |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 2 1
---------
| O     |
| O X   |
|     X |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 3 1
---------
| O     |
| O X   |
| X   X |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 2 3
---------
| O     |
| O X O |
| X   X |
---------
Enter the coordinates: 3 2
---------
| O     |
| O X O |
| X X X |
---------
X wins
```

Acá dejo mi código:

```
a = input("Enter cells: ")
lista = list(a)

def matrix():
    p = 9 * "-"
    print(p)
    print("|", lista[0], lista[1], lista[2], "|")
    print("|", lista[3], lista[4], lista[5], "|")
    print("|", lista[6], lista[7], lista[8], "|")
    print(p)

matrix()

def who_wins():
    
    while True:
        
        if lista[0] == lista[1] == lista[2] != " " and not lista[3] == lista[4] == lista[5] and not lista[6] == lista[7] == lista[8]:
            print(lista[0], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[3] == lista[4] == lista[5] != " " and not lista[0] == lista[1] == lista[2] and not lista[6] == lista[7] == lista[8]:
            print(lista[3], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[6] == lista[7] == lista[8] != " " and not lista[0] == lista[1] == lista[2] and not lista[3] == lista[4] == lista[5]:
            print(lista[6], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[0] == lista[3] == lista[6] != " " and not lista[1] == lista[4] == lista[7] and not lista[2] == lista[5] == lista[8]:
            print(lista[0], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[1] == lista[4] == lista[7] != " " and not lista[0] == lista[3] == lista[6] and not lista[2] == lista[5] == lista[8]:
            print(lista[1], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[2] == lista[5] == lista[8] != " " and not lista[0] == lista[3] == lista[6] and not lista[1] == lista[4] == lista[7]:
            print(lista[2], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[0] == lista[4] == lista[8] != " ":
            print(lista[0], "wins")
            break
        elif lista[2] == lista[4] == lista[6] != " ":
            print(lista[2], "wins")
            break
        elif " " in lista:
            continue #??????????!!!!!!!!!!!
        else:
            print("Draw")
            break

def change_player():
    pass

while True:

    n = input("Enter the coordinates: ").split()

    if (n[0].isnumeric() and n[1].isnumeric()) != True:
        print("You should enter numbers!")
        continue
    elif int(n[0]) > 3 or int(n[1]) > 3:
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
        continue
    elif lista[(int(n[0])-1)*3 + (int(n[1])-1)] in ["X", "O"]:
        print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
        continue
    else:
        lista[(int(n[0])-1)*3 + (int(n[1])-1)] = "X"
        matrix()
        who_wins()
    break
```

Comment: ¿Sabes que puedes escribir una respuesta a tu propia pregunta? Seguro que eso sería mucho más útil para otros que una simple frase "ya pude solucionarlo". Pasados unos días puedes incluso aceptar tu propia respuesta. Si lo haces no te limites a escribir el código final, explica cuál era el problema y cómo lo resolviste.

Comment: Ariel, por favor no edites la pregunta diciendo que está resuelta. Si la respuesta que hay te resolvió el problema, márcala como la respuesta aceptada. Si tú encontraste la solución, escríbela como respuesta abajo, en el campo Tu respuesta y en un rato podrás marcarla como aceptada.
Devuelvo tu edición para que lo hagas al derecho

Comment: Entendido. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final cambié completamente el código que había escrito al principio.

Esta es la función que utilicé para cambiar el turno del jugador:

```
current_player = "X"

def flip_player():

  global current_player

  if current_player == "X":
    current_player = "O"
  elif current_player == "O":
    current_player = "X"
```

Y para saber quién gana la partida o si hay empate dividí todo el distintas funciones, chequeando si hay columnas, filas y diagonales con valores de `"X"` u `"O"` iguales.

```
game_still_going = True

winner = None 

def check_game_over():
  check_winner()
  check_draw()


def check_winner():

    global winner

    row_winner = check_rows()
    column_winner = check_columns()
    diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()

    if row_winner:
        winner = row_winner
    elif column_winner:
        winner = column_winner
    elif diagonal_winner:
        winner = diagonal_winner
    else:
        winner = None


def check_rows():

    global game_still_going

    row1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != " "
    row2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != " "
    row3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != " "

    if row1 or row2 or row3:
        game_still_going = False
    if row1:
        return board[0]
    elif row2:
        return board[3]
    elif row3:
        return board[6]
    else:
        return None


def check_columns():

    global game_still_going

    column1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != " "
    column2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != " "
    column3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != " "

    if column1 or column2 or column3:
        game_still_going = False
    if column1:
        return board[1]
    elif column2:
        return board[2]
    elif column3:
        return board[6]
    else:
        return None


def check_diagonals():

    global game_still_going

    diagonal1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != " "
    diagonal2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != " "

    if diagonal1 or diagonal2:
        game_still_going = False
    if diagonal1:
        return board[0]
    elif diagonal2:
        return board[2]
    else:
        return None


def check_draw():

    global game_still_going

    if " " not in board:
        game_still_going = False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente con esta función puedes lograrlo:

```
def change_player(jugador_actual):
    if jugador_actual == 1:
        jugador_actual = 2
    else:
        jugador_actual = 1
    return jugador_actual

jugador_actual = 1
print("El jugador actual es...")
print(jugador_actual)
jugador_actual = change_player(jugador_actual)
print("Después de cambiar, el jugador es...")
print(jugador_actual)
```